# Detecting collision between rectangle and item with bezier curve shape

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem

I need to detect precisely the collision between rectangle item and another item that has a bezier curve shape. At the moment collision is detected correctly when I collide rectangle with bottom part of the bezier curve shape. But when I move rectangle inside the bezier curve shape collision is also detected, although that items aren't collided. I want to obtain a precise collision between these two items. I don't understand where I made a mistake.

[image]

```
class RectangleItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.cyan))


class CurveItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = self._setupPath()

    def paint(self, painter, styles, widget=None):
        painter.drawPath(self.path)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.path.boundingRect()

    def shape(self):
        return self.path

    def _setupPath(self):
        path = QPainterPath()

        p1 = QPointF(0, 100)
        p2 = QPointF(400, 100)
        c = QPointF(200, 800)

        path.moveTo(p1)
        path.quadTo(c, p2)
        return path


class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.curve_item = CurveItem()
        self.addItem(self.curve_item)

        self.rectangle_item = RectangleItem(0, 0, 50, 50)
        self.addItem(self.rectangle_item)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        print(self.collidingItems(self.curve_item))
        super().mouseMoveEvent(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To observe what is the cause of the problem we can place a QBrush to paint the CurveItem content and we get the following:

```
def paint(self, painter, styles, widget=None):
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor("green")))
    painter.drawPath(self.path)
```

[image]

### Why it happens?

`QPainterPath` joins the final and initial points if the figure is not closed, so it generates a figure with *content*, and that causes when you move the rectangle over the line it signals that it is intersecting.

### What is the solution?

Go back through the same path to the starting point, thus joining the new final line with the initial one without generating the *content*.

In the following code is the solution:

```
class CurveItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = self._setupPath()

    def paint(self, painter, styles, widget):
        painter.drawPath(self.path)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.path.boundingRect()

    def shape(self):
        return self.path

    def _setupPath(self):
        path = QPainterPath()

        p1 = QPointF(0, 100)
        p2 = QPointF(400, 100)
        c = QPointF(200, 800)

        path.moveTo(p1)
        path.quadTo(c, p2)

        # back
        path.quadTo(c, p1)
        return path
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you !